# Get Entire Hierarchy of Parents From a Given Child in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is a sample of the data I am looking at:

Table:

```
id     |    name    |   parent_id
_______|____________|______________
1      |Root        | null
2      |Parent #2   | 1
3      |Parent #3   | 1
4      |Parent #4   | 2
5      |Child #5    | 2
6      |Child #6    | 2
7      |Child #7    | 3
8      |Child #8    | 3
9      |Child #9    | 3
```

Using a recursive query, I am able to start from a Parent, and get all associated children.

My question is, how can I start at the child, and get all related parents, grandparents, etc, right up to the root.

So, given Child #9, I would like a query that returns the following:

```
id     |    name    |   parent_id
_______|____________|______________
1      |Root        | 0
3      |Parent #3   | 1
9      |Child #9    | 3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like this:

```
with recursive whosYourDaddy as (

  --start with the "anchor" row
  select
    *
  from foo
  where
    id = 9 --parameterize me

  union all

  select
    foo.*
  from foo 
  join whosYourDaddy on whosYourDaddy.parent_id = foo.id
)

select
  *
from whosYourDaddy 
order by
  id;
```

Result:

```
id  name      parent_id
-----------------------
1   Root      (null)
3   Parent 3  1
9   Child 9   3
```

Code:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a5fb9/12

Comment: Thanks, @neil-mcguian, that did it!  I had to change `union all` to `union` as the query ran continuously until my computer ran out of space.  With just the `union`, the query ran quickly, and the results were exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What if the id's are not in order?

Comment: Can this result be used as a subquery to get the "combined" hierarchy in an own attribute of a master query?